# Accessing guest (Ubuntu) localhost from host (Windows)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is there any way to access guest's localhost through a browser inside the host? I am running Ubuntu with Virtualbox on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure network interface for guest system. E.g. bridge should help you.
Or you can use port forwarding through NAT.

Look at [official docs](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) to more info.